# Can you dynamically get parent component classname in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible for a reactjs child component to dynamically determine the class of its parent component? I have a component that can be rendered inside a handful of different components, and I want it to act differently depending on which parent it is. Is it possible to do this without passing in a flag to the child component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think about it like this:

```
Component needs data to render → Pass data as prop.
```

Anything else goes against the point of react.

Comment: In this case, the data I would be passing would have to be a flag for the parent (i.e. the name of the parent calling this child). I was hoping there was a way I could get the same effect without having to pass something through. I'll just pass a flag along in the props.